# Android 3g blocks UDP?

Tags: android, udp, 3g

I'm working on a small test case. I have a udp server on a dedicated server at a hoster. Next i have a udp client running on my android g1.

When i turn on 3g on my android g1 the packet that the udp client sends doesn't reach the udp server on my server.

When i run the client on the android emulator everything works perfect, the client sends packet and gets a response from server.

I tried running the youtube app and streaming movie is possible (i suspected that is done with udp?)

The udp server listens on 8080, i also tried 40. But no luck.

My 3g provider is t-mobile.

Does somebody know how i can figure out if t-mobile is blocking udp packets?

Answer (score 0):

Is the udp server remote reachable? Check nmap  to see if the port is forwarded andanother thing is, when you run your setup behind a NAT you will not reach your local server as long you are not  forwarding the port.

Comment: The udp server works on the emulator and with a normal client program running on any computer. I tried logging in as root with adb shell on my g1, but nmap isn't available. I can ping my dedicated server which hosts the udp server. I can also browse to my server. Only when sending udp packages with android it doesn't work. I'm going to put my SIM card in my netbook and try the udp client there.

Comment: I got my netbook working with my android sim card. I directly tried my udp client, the udp packets don't get to my server. Next i ran nmap and it says: 7/udp open/filtered . In the docs it says that filtered means that a firewall is blocking the port. I also run nmap on my local linux server and that says that the port is open. I guess i'm out of luck with udp. I will try more common udp ports

Comment: some providers filter certain tcp/udp packets, to be safe try to use common ports such as 80, 21, 8080, etc